# python3 django-admin syntax error

Tags: django, django-admin

trying to learn python/django.
after installing all the bits and pieces getting this error (see list). please point into right direction. thank you!

```
$ django-admin startproject test1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/django-admin", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('Django==2.1', 'console_scripts', 'django-admin')()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 561, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2627, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2287, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2293, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from django.conf import settings
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from django.utils.functional import LazyObject, empty
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 12
    return _curried_func(*args, *moreargs, **{**kwargs, **morekwargs})
                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Python 3.5.0a4 (v3.5.0a4:413e0e0004f4, Apr 19 2015, 14:18:20) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5577)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import django
>>> print(django.get_version())

2.1
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using an alpha version of Python 3.5 - update your Python to the latest stable 3.5 release.